# ExportAsFixedFormat as PDF System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:

Tags: excel, vb.net, export-to-pdf

I am trying to send data from my application in Visual Studio vb.net to a template .xls that i would then like to save as a .pdf.
Everything works fine except for when it tries to export as pdf and save the file i get the following exception;

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.'
```

I am using the following code:

```
    Private Sub exportXlsData()

        'Gets resource path of template
        Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
        Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "Template.xlsx")

        'dims excel
        Dim xls As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        'opens sheet
        xls = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
        xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
        xls.Visible = False

        'export data to excel
        xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "TEST WORKS YEWWW"

        'save pdf
        xlsWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "c:\test.pdf")

        xlsWorkBook.Close()
        xls.Quit()

    End Sub
```

I know the issues is with

```
xlsWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "c:\test.pdf")
```

and have tried some different scenarios such as

```
xlsWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= -
```

But visual studio doesn't recognize xlTypePDF.

I have Office 365 and have added the reference.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `xlTypePDF` corresponds to `0` so that shouldn't be it. Do you have permission to write to that location?

Comment: shouldn't or should? i checked online and PDF was 0, and XPS was 1 - I believe i have permission as i'm the admin but i will try another location.

Comment: Meaning that `0` shouldn't be the problem, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: no problem :) - Well it seems that i didn't have permission for C: looks like i need a break from staring at the screen haha, thank you my friend.